# How can I bypass the password save suggestion for my label (which isn't a username + password)?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, label, passwords

I have a price label where the user can enter any price number so lets say "1200", then he has to add a file and finally to confirm it all he has to enter is password.

The problem is that everytime that the form is completed successfully (image 1), there is always a save the password suggestion that pop up (image 2) even if the price label "Prix" isn't a username label...

I am using Google Chrome for my demo.

I tried to change the value of the label, but nothing changes...

I would Google or any other browser to stop considering these as username + password combinaisons and simply stop suggesting to save as user pwd.

Thank you for your help.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]